# Can I delete folder Developer-3.2.5?

Tags: xcode

I saw a similar question ([Can I delete the /Developer-3.2.6 or /Developer-3.2.5 folders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25213/can-i-delete-the-developer-3-2-6-folder)), but I am unclear if it would break anything. That question assumes the user is not a developer, so I was a little worried and would like to be sure before I do anything. Can I delete this folder? I updated to Xcode 4, but I am unsure if deleting this would remove things that I may need. For example, before Xcode 4 came out, I installed Xcode 3 to compile my C programs (gcc).

Right now, there is a Developer and a Developer-3.2.5 folder, so I assume Developer is for Xcode4 stuff.

Comment: he mentioned that in his post, I would say they should be merged or one of these marked as closed.

Comment: The referenced question has good answers. You can remove this folder as all the functionality is duplicated in later versions of the developer tools. The exceptions are rare and older versions of Xcode are available to download from Apple's Developer web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely delete the folder Developer-3.2.5 - it shouldn't effect your workflow in any way UNLESS you want to add an older SDK at a later date.

If you are interested in seeing more discussion about it, there is also an [Apple Support Community thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2780986?start=0&tstart=0) that essentially says the same thing - that you don't need the folders.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe to delete, if for no other reason than if something *does* get messed up, you can just reinstall Xcode 4.

Comment: Indeed. With any of the Xcode 3 versions, you can delete things by hand or use the included script `sudo  /Developer-3.x.y/Library/uninstall-devtools.pl -mode=all` to be sure all the old versions of gcc are cleaned up.